# Adding hours and mins with now() sql to hql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm working with spring,hibernate and mysql. I want my timezone's date and time. I'm from Sri Lanka, so I want to add ***+5 hours 30 mins*** with `now()` function in sql;

I wrote a query and ran it in sql workbench, its working fine.

```
SELECT date_add(date_add(now(),INTERVAL +5 HOUR),INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
```

> The DATE_ADD() function returns a date after a certain time/date
>   interval has been added.
>   But when I adding to hql, it throws error. My full query in hql is

```
FROM Survey where  convert(endDateTime, datetime)< date_add(date_add(now(),INTERVAL +5 HOUR),INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
```

When I use this above code in sql workbench, its working fine. But it does not  work in hql.

Error is

```
 nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: expecting CLOSE, found 'HOUR' near line 1, column 114 [FROM com.pulseBeatMaster.model.Survey where  convert(endDateTime, datetime)< date_add(date_add(now(),INTERVAL +5 HOUR),INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found 'HOUR' near line 1, column 114 [FROM com.pulseBeatMaster.model.Survey where  convert(endDateTime, datetime)< date_add(date_add(now(),INTERVAL +5 HOUR),INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)]] with root cause
```

Is there any method to get my timezone's current date and time or add ***+5 hours 30 mins*** with `now()`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not calculate the time in HQL or SQL. calculate it in java

Comment: Pretty much waht @Jen

Comment: Campare in sql is working @Jens. Example `FROM Survey where  convert(endDateTime, datetime)< now();` So its not a problem

Comment: SQL is not HQL!

Comment: Yeah, you want minimize places where you have to manage such things as time. if you're doing it on web server, do it on web server, if youre doing it all on db server, fine, but I find it more practical to do it on java just because java is more expressive and easier to manage than in sql and sql server itself

Comment: @Medardas I can do it in java, the problem is I want to recall the function in every 5 sec. So I thought doing query is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much what @Jens said, I don't think currently HQL supports all date functions, either calculate the date in your code (should be quite simple), or use a native query since you don't seem to use any query parameters.

Extra, the fact that convert exists, does not mean that date_add or date_sub exists.

In the majority of cases the date would be calculated on the code, even if just for easiness of re-using the same query in case you just want to change some data.

Comment: like @Jens said, calculate the date in java. and then use hql: FROM Survey where  convert(endDateTime, datetime)<:dateToCompare.

Then you just have to set the dateToCompare

Comment: I'm seriously mad, its a easiest solution, thank you so much.

`LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
String hql = "FROM Survey where status=1 and convert(endDateTime, datetime)<:dateNow";
Query query = (Query) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
  query.setParameter("dateNow", now);`

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't work when you need to compare 2 different columns. For example, you would like to check if one date column + some hours from another column are greater than the current time..

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative for you from [mysql timzone support doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html):

> You can set the system time zone for MySQL Server at startup with the --timezone=timezone_name option to mysqld_safe.

Or

> If you have the SUPER privilege, you can set the global server time zone value at runtime with this statement:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+5:30';
```